# How to manage Parent-Child Hierarchy in Git

Tags: git, bitbucket, parent-child, branching-and-merging

I want to get the idea on how to manage the Parent-Child Hierarchy in `git`.
Let's say I have a `master` branch where code will be updated once a week. I have made a new branch say `MainDev` for development. 
When the team works, they create branches on their local like `NewBranch`.
I have 2 questions:

- How can I push the newly created branch only to `MainDev` so that, `MainDev` and all the pull requests I create, should be merged only on `MainDev`?
- Is there any way that BitBucket automatically merges the `MainDev` branch to master and updates `master` and `MainDev` once a week?

Comment: Relevant: [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), which describes in essence what you're accomplishing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git flow branching model branching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941466/git-flow-branching-model-branching)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No automatic merge tools that I know of with BitBucket, but regarding PRs you may want to change your default branch through the repo's admin page.

Comment: regarding automatic merge, I can do that manually, but if I do `git push MainDev NewBranch`, this will push the code to only `MainDev` and branch will be created UNDER `MainDev`?

Comment: If you want to push code to `MainDev` and create a new branch from `MainDev`, you should run `git push` while on `MainDev`, then `git branch NewBranch` to create new branch from `MainDev`.

Comment: I am always on `MainDev`, should I do
1. git pull (on `MainDev`)
2. git branch `NewBranch.Num`
3. make changes
4. `git add -filenames`
5. `git push` on `MainDev`

are the steps right for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. What are you trying to accomplish by syncing the local and remote repositories and creating a new branch?

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to create a new branch locally from `MainDev`, make changes on that branch, and then push those changes on the new branch to the remote repository? (That's the suggested workflow for both Git and GitHub.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113814/discussion-between-baig772-and-briana-swift).